# How to retrieve a comment's photo in the Facebook SDK v4

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been messing around with the facebook SDK v4 for php and I noticed that posts with photo comment's don't have a link for the image. Included is an example of what I mean. Does anyone know how to get the photo comment so I can see what the comment is? Or am I just not doing something right?

The array of comment data

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object (
  [id] => 10152439171190829_10152439172785829
  [from] => stdClass Object (
    [id] => 10152145221271615
    [name] => Todd 
  )
  [message] =>
  [can_remove] =>
  [created_time] => 2014-08-24T01:42:19+0000
  [like_count] => 2
  [user_likes] => 1
)
[1] => stdClass Object (
  [id] => 10152439171190829_10152439451215829
  [from] => stdClass Object (
    [id] => 318874908277303
    [name] => Andrew 
  )
  [message] =>
  [can_remove] =>
  [created_time] => 2014-08-24T04:45:32+0000
  [like_count] => 1
  [user_likes] => 1
 )
)
```

What it looks like on facebook 
[image: photo]

As you can clearly see, the comments don't have a photo according to the api...

### Update

I have been looking around and still don't see the answer anywhere.

### Update

Still no update on any of this.

Comment: Has anyone come up with a possible work around for this?